# Is there a name for this kind of algebra?

Tags: terminology

Suppose we have two binary operations $+$ and $*$. Suppose they are free objects in the variety of magmas. That is, the only equations they satisfy are when both terms on each side are identical terms. However, suppose that $*$ but not $+$ satisfy an additional constraint, which is that if $x*y$=$z*w$, then $x=z$ and $y=w$. What kind of name is used for this kind of operation? I thought it was "free object in the quasivariety of magmas", but I am not sure.

Comment: It’s no longer free when you add that constraint, right? And your purpose is not very clear to me: what does the addition have to do with your question? It seems like you can ignore it since you ask only about $*$ - they don’t even seem to be operations on the same set (although I am sort of guessing you have that in mind)

Comment: Yes, you can just ignore it.

Comment: You still haven’t answered the main question: is $*$ actually free or is it a free object modulo a relation?

Comment: @TokenToucan I mean this. The only equations that $*$ satisfy are $t=t$, for a term $t$. But also, it satisfies the condition that if $x*y=z*w$, then $x=y$ and also $z=w$. To give a concrete example, natural numbers with tetration satisfy the first condition, but not the second.

Comment: First, there is no magma at all that work with your first condition: the terms $"(a)"$  and $"a"$ are distinct but satisfy $(a) = a$. Second, you still haven't written things out carefully: you cannot insist that something *only* satisfies X (this "free" business) and then also ask that it satisfies Y (the extra relation) unless, for instance, you know Y follows from X. Lastly, I am pretty sure that a correct version of your freeness statement (e.g. actual freeness) implies the second condition and so your example with tetrations can't be sound.

Comment: I don't mean to be abrasive but I can't tell if you actual *mean* free when you say free, or you're asking whether free (whichever definition) implies the extra relation you want, or if you're asking for a name for the second property. In any case, the probable answer is that there is no name.

Comment: @TokenToucan I apologize. I don't really know what free means. But what I mean by it, in the context of magmas, is that the operation does not satisfy any non-trivial equations. A term in that language, is something like $(x*x)*(y*z)$. Basically, we have a countably infinite set of variables, and we build terms in that language using that operation. So, I am saying the only equations that it satisfies are of the form $t=t$. I don't know if that is the definition of free, but regardless, that is what I am talking about.